R: How to combine several nested dataframes
considre this MWE:
library(magrittr)

data <- tibble::tibble(
  company = c(
    "Google",
    "Apple"
  )
) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(patents = purrr::map(
    .x = company,
    .f = function(x) {
      data <- patentsview::search_pv(
        query = patentsview::qry_funs$contains(assignee_organization = x),
        fields = c(
          "app_number",
          "app_country",
          "app_date",
          "patent_abstract",
          "patent_date",
          "patent_number",
          "patent_title"
        ),
        sort = c("app_date" = "asc"),
        endpoint = "patents",
        mtchd_subent_only = FALSE
      )

      patentsview::unnest_pv_data(data$data, pk = "patent_number") %>%
        lapply(FUN = tibble::as_tibble) %>%
        as.matrix() %>%
        t() %>%
        tibble::as_tibble()
    }
  )) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c(patents)) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "company") %>%
  t() %>%
  tibble::as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique", rownames = NA)

which results in a dataframe like this:
> data
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Google            Apple            
* <list>            <list>           
1 <tibble [25 × 5]> <tibble [25 × 5]>
2 <tibble [25 × 4]> <tibble [25 × 4]>

In this example I am using only two companies, but in the real application the number of companies is dynamic. How can I combine the nested dataframes from the different companies into one single dataframe per row?
So it looks like this:
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Google              Apple             Combined
* <list>              <list>            <list>
  1 <tibble [25 × 5]> <tibble [25 × 5]> <tibble [50 × 5]> 
  2 <tibble [25 × 4]> <tibble [25 × 4]> <tibble [50 × 4]> 


You may use rowwise from dplyr to combine rows in a row-wise fashion.
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(combined = list(bind_rows(c_across()))) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 × 3
#  Google            Apple             combined         
#  <list>            <list>            <list>           
#1 <tibble [25 × 5]> <tibble [25 × 5]> <tibble [50 × 5]>
#2 <tibble [25 × 4]> <tibble [25 × 4]> <tibble [50 × 4]>


I never heared about rowwise, and I often missed this feature, you made my day, thank you :-)
